# Insert text from file into TEXT field

Tags: mysql

I have the following TABLE with fields

```
#    id (INT)    |    file_content (TEXT)
-----------------------------------------
1    1           |    NULL
2    2           |    NULL
```

I want update the contents of the TEXT field `file_content` via CLI by adding the contents of a file as new value.

I was thinking of something like this

```
mysql -u root -p mydb -e "UPDATE mytable SET file_content = '$(cat filename)';"
```

This seems a bit like a hack, though. Is there a better way to do this?
Is this approach generally vulnerable to SQL injection? I know the contents of the file I am adding but I would still like some general feedback on this approach for future reference.

Comment: it is a hideous hack, and you would be badly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) doing that. Any particular reason you have to store your files in the db? there's very few usage cases where the benefits outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: agreed w/ marc.. why not storing only paths?

Comment: @MarcB Well, the files are not that big. I would like to port the database to another system eventually without having to update the paths. Besides that, I am still new to MySQL and at this point this is also a learning experience. I just would like to know how to achieve this, even if it is not that common.

Comment: Using a scripting layer, be it Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Node.js or anything else that tickles your fancy, is almost *always* better than trying to do it in MySQL exclusively. What's trivial to do in a scripting language is often really difficult and annoying in SQL because it was never intended to be a general purpose scripting tool.

Comment: @tadman My scripting layer is supposed to be Bash. I do not consider this a pure MySQL approach.

Comment: "Supposed to be"? Bash isn't a general purpose scripting language, it's highly dependent on external tools like `sed` to get anything useful done.

Comment: and bash cannot/will not be able to issue a proper prepared statement with placeholders, meaning you'll have to handle sql injection problems MANUALLY, which is never a good thing.